# Detecting on- and off-state of a micro switch

Tags: switches, current-measurement, reliability

For safety reasons I need to make sure that I am still detecting the correct state of a micro switch and not for example a loss of power, broken cable, etc.

What are cheap and reliable ways of doing this?

To be clear, I need three kinds of signals (examples in parenthesis), on (I=5 mA), off (I=1mA), cable broken/etc. (I=0mA).

If possible I'd prefer some theory behind the solution(s), a book with the basics of such circuits for references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well if you know your currents, why don't you use a current to voltage circuit? Then the result can go into your microcontroller, or whatever you are using to read the signal

Comment: @MCG maybe I wasn't clear, I have a switch which has an on and an off state and need to integrate it into a circuit to have 3 states afterwards - namely on, off and fault. Natively the switch won't let current through in the off state, which I need to compensate. And I'm looking for tested / known solutions.

Comment: What level of solution are you looking for? discrete? IC? PLC?  There are infinite ways to encode this.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 as simple as possible, I'd prefer discrete.

Comment: how long is the cable? How often does it change, how fast, stable must it be? (latency?) WHat is it detecting? high voltage active on grid?

Comment: Is one microswitch "enough" to guarantee the level of safety required?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 nothing fancy. Andyaka: yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, you can't change the switch to a SPDT one, which would be the simplest.

Therefore, a possible solution (keeping the SPST switch you have now) is to add a resistor in parallel with the switch. Here is an example with a 5V supply and the currents you suggested in your example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6ITU7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here, there are four possible states you can detect:

- 5mA when the switch is closed
- 1mA when the switch is opened
- 0mA when one of the long wire is broken (fault)
- 10mA when the long wires are shorted (fault)

Of course, you can't cover ALL kind of fault cases. For example, if the switch itself is broken (stays closed or opened all the time), you won't be able to detect this. Same if there is one faulty resistor. What you can detect here is when the *long wires* link is faulty.

Now, regarding the theory behind this: just Ohm's law.

Comment: ... if the long wires develop a short?

Comment: @Andyaka Then, indeed, you won't see it. You could fix that by adding and additional resistor is series with the SW1||R2 (on the right side of the long wires), though. I'll add this, thanks.

Comment: Do you know if this is used somewhere? Is it a standard solution to this problem or is the problem mostly solved different when it happens in real life? Or does it not happen? It does seem to do exactly what I want it to.

Comment: @DonQuiKong If this is for safety reasons the OP will need two switches in series not just a single switch. Mechanically they need to be separated too.

Comment: @Trevor_G it's not so much safety in the sense of "the plane will crash if the fault isn't detected", rather like "it would be nice to have a cheap solution telling me if I'm still sensing the off position or just a broken connection"

Comment: @DonQuiKong This technique is most probably used in some real products, although I am not able to give a specific example. But since it only relies on basic stuff, I don't see why other engineers would be reluctant to use it, provided that it fits the purpose. However, yes, these kind of problems often find a specific solution depending on the constraints of the products (possibility to use a SPDT, need to detect other kind of faults, risks involved, ...). There is no "standard" way to solve this.

Comment: @DonQuiKong do some research into burglar alarm sensors.

Comment: @DonQuiKong although that is true, if this is indeed a safety feature, to pass safety inspection you will need two fault protection. One switch will not be enough. In fact with a complex circuit as indicated here, you may need to dupplicate the whole thing. \Rereading your comment., though, it appears that may not be the requirement here.

Comment: "Same if there is one faulty resistor." Actually you would be able to detect most of them other than R2 shorted. Using two in series for R2 would therefore be better.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if something like this would work, but if you have a SPDT Switch you could put 2 resistors in series with the NO and NC contacts.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCGJly.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>